# Error while running depswriter.py from google closure library

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library, xtk

I am trying to build **XTK** following [this link](https://github.com/xtk/X/wiki/X:DevelopersHeadsUp) on Linux running on Oracle VirtualBox to get non-minified `xtk.js`. I am getting following error when I tried to generate the `xtk-deps.js` on running `deps.py` file:

```
Generating dependency file for XTK...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/Downloads/X-master/lib/google-closure-library/closure/bin/build/depswriter.py", line 212, in <module>
main()
File "/root/Downloads/X-master/lib/google-closure-library/closure/bin/build/depswriter.py", line 196, in main
path_to_source[depspath] = source.Source(source.GetFileContents(srcpath))
File "/root/Downloads/X-master/lib/google-closure-library/closure/bin/build/source.py", line 126, in GetFileContents
return fileobj.read()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 668, in read
return self.reader.read(size)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 474, in read
newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8_sig.py", line 104, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 4584: invalid start byte
Could not generate dependency file.
```

Could anybody please explain why this error is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is that I used an earlier commit of [google closure library](https://github.com/4u/closure-library/tree/839dfc1ead60090843b221141512fa83973708c8) for building [XTK](https://github.com/xtk/X) and it worked perfectly.
I had to search XTK's commit history extensively to know which version of closure library they were using to build it.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably some non-uft8 characters in your code (most likely in **X.js**).

Take my experience for example, in the **X.js** of XTK, I found there's a non-English word (maybe a German or French name) in line #210. What I did is to delete the character and run build.py again. The encode error didn't appear again.